# Archive public folder in Exchange 2003?

Tags: exchange-2003

We are using Exchange Server 2003 and I want to archive the public folder in Exchange. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: What do you mean "archive the public folder"? Do you want to export the content? If so, you can do that from Outlook.

Answer (score 0):

We just evaluated some products for archiving public folders (+500GB) on our exchange 2003 enterprise and we will be putting [mailstore server](http://www.mailstore.com) in production pretty soon. 
We chose it because the ease of use/licensing and the price tag. While trying it we had 
to contact support twice, and it was top notch even with the eval licence.

Without third party products you have to stick with .pst files on exchange 2003 with all the downsides.